# Is there a way to save the rectangle behind a child window?

Tags: c++, windows

The question is in context of Windows, and C++.

To clarify, in xlib, it is possible to tell server to save behind a (popup) window. Then, when the child window is hidden only what was behind it is drawn without having to refresh the entire top-window and all children (controls).

Now, I show a button (say for a tip), and then when I hide it, I do not want to repaint everything. Instead, I want to just draw whatever was covered by the button before showing it.

My searches do not seem to hit anything useful. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: What about InvalidateRect?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect  If you don't pass a rectangle then it repaints the entire client area but you can pass a rectangle.

Comment: The problem is that, it may be touching several controls. Once I hide it, Windows wants to repaint everything it was touching. Can this be avoided.

Comment: We need to close this, accepting that there is no solution. Thanks anyway.